# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not executed - Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I am using **Parse.com** to send push notification in my iOS app.
but when i execute following code to create `PFInstallation` object,the device token field is blank.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xhjhkk869698lhlljk554hl55khlkhl4ff99065" clientKey:@"spg1t6jad1ShK2lh5456khh6j7j4nmn1YD6J6rl8vt3"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

// Register for push notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
return YES;
```

}

I noticed that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is never executed. i cross checked my certificates and provisioning profile and i tested them using method specified [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) (see under **Making a PEM file**). Certificates and connection work fine. I also checked if my wifi is blocking the push notification,there is no issue with it.

so can anyone Please suggest what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the alert poping when you register for remote notifications?

Comment: Are you testing the app on device or simulator?

Comment: Have you created a apns certificate and re-generated the provisioning profile after that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33673/discussion-between-ashish-pisey-and-soryngod)

Comment: @soryngod yes u did it. created a apns certificate and re-generated the provisioning profile after that. it worked

Comment: Great!!! Glad that I could help. Remember to do that, because the entitlements for apns are update in the mobile provisioning profile after you allow the app to receive the push notifications.

Answer (score 22):

Did you implement? `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` 
Maybe you have some error and in this method you can get description of it.

Comment: Important information for anyone trying to track down the problem.

Comment: Very weird issue for me. on *iOS 10 swift 3* my code was perfect but i wasn't calling. i open WIFI/Internet connection on my device. closed app and relaunch. RegisterRemoteNotification did call

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in my applications to register for push notifications:

In AppDelegate.m

```
#pragma mark PUSH NOTIFICATION

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
    NSUInteger rntypes;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    rntypes = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];
} else {
    rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
}
    // Set the defaults to disabled unless we find otherwise...
    NSString *pushBadge = @"disabled";
    NSString *pushAlert = @"disabled";
    NSString *pushSound = @"disabled";

    if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)
    {
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)
    {
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)
    {
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert))
    {
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound))
    {
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound))
    {
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }
    else if(rntypes == ( UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound))
    {
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
        pushAlert = @"enabled";
        pushSound = @"enabled";
    }

    NSLog(@"PUSH SOUND %@",pushBadge);
    NSLog(@"PUSH ALERT %@",pushAlert);
    NSLog(@"PUSH SOUND %@",pushSound);

    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[token description]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"%d bytes", [token length]);
    NSLog(@"device token = %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    for (id key in userInfo)
    {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }

    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);

    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:alert delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

And put this into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Comment: thanx for ur response. why are u enabling push notification types conditionally? Is that your app specific requirement?                            what i did in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not sufficient ?

Comment: I am doing it conditionally to unable or disable the badge,alert or sound!! and your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is sufficient though!!